# toggle image on hover using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

*First of all please dont suggest me to do this using css.*

I need to toggle between two images on-hover using Jquery.
I need that two images (two toggling images) should be downloaded at the time of page load. Cause else it will create a lag time for the first time. As my images are two banners on the home page.I need to do something creating a image object , thus pre-loading it and later on toggling the objects.

I cant do this using simple css cause there will be a lag for the first time user as the image is not present on page load. and it gives a bad look.

Comment: I found this question looking for something else, but you could use CSS to toggle these images, and have the images on your page in <img> tags, with display set to none.  This will do the whole process without javascript.

Comment: @AndrewJackman Please read the question again, I clearly specified: I cant do this using simple css cause there will be a lag for the first time for user as the image is not present on page load. and it gives a bad look.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand your reasoning, but there is a way to have the image load up on page load. If you have `<img src='image.jpg' style='display:none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px;' />` at the bottom of the body tag.  Then, if you use `image.jpg` later on through a hover effect, there will be no lag because the browser will have already downloaded the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   var imgs = [
       new Image(),
       new Image()
   ];

   imgs[0].src = 'http://www.typeofnan.com/pic1.jpg';
   imgs[1].src = 'http://www.typeofnan.com/pic2.jpg';

   $('#hoverelement').hover(function(){
      $(this).html(imgs[0]);
   }, function(){
      $(this).html(imgs[1]);
   });
});​
```

That should work, even if I'm not sure if that is what you need. You can add an `onload` event to both images to makes sure, they are really loaded before allowing hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Quick  Demo  of below Code : **http://jsbin.com/itunu**

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Hello world !!</title>

</head>
<body>
  <img  />
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
var a = [];

a[0] = "http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss219/music_munster/powerpuff-girls-092.jpg";
a[1] = "http://img.listal.com/image/459059/500full.jpg";


$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = $.preload(a); 
  $('img').attr('src',source[0].src); //just an acknowledgement (pre-loading done)
  $('img').hover(function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[1].src);
  },function() {
    $('img').attr('src',source[0].src);    
  });

});



//Image Preloading....  
var cache = [];
  $.preload = function(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = arr[i];
      cache.push(img);
    }
    return cache;
  };
```