# how to toggle attr in jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to toggle between two images when the user hovers on a div. Is there a way to do it?
Can I use a boolean flag that is updated every time I hover the div and then use this flag to toggle images? Can someone let me know if that's the right way to do it?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.my-element').on('mouseenter', function () {             
            $('img#element_1').attr({
                'src': 'img/../element 1.png'
            });             
        });     
    });
```

The first time I hover the mouse on div it should toggle my image. The next time the image toggles is when my mouse hovers the div again, instead of when the mouse leaves after the first toggle.

Comment: Where is your mouseleave handler that reverts the changes you made in the mouseenter?

Comment: Here's the problem: since (like I mention) I trigger animation, the my-element div is moving once hover, so if I'll use the mouseleave it will change immdiatly - because the element is moving. I want that it'll change (toggle) again only once hover again

Comment: See if you can try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557053/9362838

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I solved it. I just used a boolean helper variable. I first declared as true.

```
var myHelper = true;
```

then I used condition to check `if (myHelper) then $().attr`
and with another condition I check `if (!myHelper) then ..`

and in the end of the script I put `myHelper = !myHelper` so it always toggles

It works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that you can take. You can check the same in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/q4z7o4ry/2/ (Please make sure you use JavaScript + jQuery in the bottom left box)

If you have the html like:

```
<div class="my-element" style="border: 1px solid red; width:150px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <img id="element_1" src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/javascript/javascript-card.png" height="150" width="150" />
</div>
```

JavaScript/Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.my-element').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var img1 = 'https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/javascript/javascript-card.png';
    var img2 = 'https://brand.jquery.org/resources/jquery-mark-light.gif';
    var curr_src = $('img#element_1').attr('src');
    var toggled_src = curr_src == img1 ? img2 : img1;
    $('img#element_1').attr('src', toggled_src);
  });
});
```

Or you can have two images in the div and show one of them at a time. HTML code would look like:

```
<div class="my-element1" style="border: 1px solid red; width:150px;">
  <img id="element_2" src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/javascript/javascript-card.png" height="150" width="150" />
  <img id="element_3" src="https://brand.jquery.org/resources/jquery-mark-light.gif" height="150" width="150" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

And the JavaScript/JQuery code would go like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.my-element1').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('img#element_2').toggle();
    $('img#element_3').toggle();
  });

});
```

Hope this helps.